# How do I implement a "sliding out of / into" effect on a settings menu similar to that in Angry Birds?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to implement a settings menu component similar to that in Angry Birds - a button control that makes an options menu slide out of it and back into it when clicked on.

I use `scene2d.ui` to build the UI components: a `Button` in a `Table` to implement the button control, a `Table` to implement the options menu, and a `Stack` to lay these out one on top of the other and at this moment I have the following behavior:

1. When the user hits the button control for the first time, then the alpha of the table component is set to 1;
2. When the user hits the button control the second time, then the alpha of the table component is set to 0;
   And so on.

Any ideas how I can get the sliding out of and into effect on user clicks with libgdx? Similar to what Angry Birds provides.

Maybe using the TweenEngine, actions, interpolations, combinations of these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Tween Engine; examples can be found here: [Dermetfan Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PqwxYVlivA) [Aurelien Ribon App Test](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/source/browse/tween-engine-demo/src/aurelienribon/tweenengine/tests/libgdx/App.java?r=fd9033132763f5416359d2856d8c22e4a68d8093)